# Facebook Graph API to retrieve tagged images of myself

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook Graph API with an `access_token` for myself (generated using the Graph API Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer )

I want to retrieve all photos I am tagged in.  I'm starting at this endpoint:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/

I can page through them fine, but there are only 109 photos before there are no more results.

On my Facebook profile, under "Photos" -> "Photos of You" there are many more than 109.

Why are all the photos not available to me through the Graph API?

Comment: Did you figure it out?